# Animate Elements With Same Class Independantly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list with multiple nested unordered lists.  I'm trying to animate the multiple nested `<ul></ul>` independantly to a random position in the containing div.  I've got the random position part, but its giving that position to each nested `<ul></ul>` rather than give each one is own random position.  In the HTML below I am trying to give each class `mapStart-second` its own unique random position, both in this case, they are both getting the same position.

Example HTML

```
<ul id="mapStart">  

    <li id="mapStart-first">

        <ul class="mapStart-second">
            <li></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="mapStart-second">
            <li></li>
        </ul>

    </li>

</ul>
```

JS/jQuery

```
jQuery('#mapStart-first').one('mouseenter', function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.mapStart-second').fadeIn('slow').animate({
        top: Math.floor((Math.random()*aw_positionY)),
        left: Math.floor((Math.random()*aw_positionX)),
    });     
});
```

The variables `aw_positionsX` and aw_positionY are also being dynamically set and working correctly.

Comment: Right off the bat I can see that 
`jQuery('#mapStart-first').one('mouseenter', function() {`
should be
`jQuery('#mapStart-first').on('mouseenter', function() {`

Comment: @inorganik `one` is a jQuery function that attaches an event listener to be run only once (first mouseenter). I'm assuming that's intended.

Comment: Yes, that was intended.  I only want it to happen once.

Comment: well then I stand corrected. I knew about one(), but I figured he meant on().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a loop, or you'll be passing the same random values to each animation:

```
jQuery('#mapStart-first').one('mouseenter', function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.mapStart-second').fadeIn('slow').each(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            top: Math.floor((Math.random()*aw_positionY)),
            left: Math.floor((Math.random()*aw_positionX)),
        });   
    });  
});
```

Comment: I tried different variations with `.each()`, but couldn't get it to work.  I'll try yours now.